# Repeat a range a number of times

Tags: excel, excel-formula, repeat, excel-lambda

I have a simple problem, but I am not quite able to figure out the answer

[image]

Given a range (in blue), and a number of times to be repeated (in orange), I need to create 2 spill arrays in vertical:

- the first one repeats the range the desired number of times
- the second one repeats each element of the range the desired number of times

I have looked for a solution with `REDUCE` & `VSTACK`, but I do not mind if the functions are different.

I have tried, for example, with

```
=LET(a, SEQUENCE(F2), REDUCE("",B5:B7,LAMBDA(x,y,VSTACK(x,y))))
```

... but the range is not repeated.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the first:

```
=LET(r,FILTER(A:A,A:A<>""),cnt,B1,INDEX(r,MOD(SEQUENCE(COUNTA(r) *cnt,,0),COUNTA(r))+1))
```

[image]

for the second:

```
=LET(r,FILTER(A:A,A:A<>""),cnt,B1,INDEX(r,SEQUENCE(COUNTA(r) *cnt,,1,1/cnt)))
```

[image]

Both in one:

```
=LET(r,FILTER(A:A,A:A<>""),cnt,B1,INDEX(r,HSTACK(MOD(SEQUENCE(COUNTA(r) *cnt,,0),COUNTA(r))+1,SEQUENCE(COUNTA(r) *cnt,,1,1/cnt))))
```

[image]

Comment: There seems to be a small problem with your formulas. When I increase the namber of elements in the range from 3 to 4, the formulas are no longer valid. Could you please check if there is a problem?

Comment: I edited the formulas many many times, make sure you are grabbing the current.  You may need to refresh the page to see it.

Comment: you're right, when I take your latest version, it works fine, thank you

Comment: This is great and just what I needed! I've just got 365 after being stuck on 2016 for years so playing catch-up with some of the new functionality. I took the liberty of creating a lambda function out of your solution that I call Rept_Range;

```=LAMBDA(range,number_times,[grouped_stack],LET(filtered,FILTER(range,range<>""),IF(OR(ISOMITTED(grouped_stack),NOT(grouped_stack)),INDEX(filtered,MOD(SEQUENCE(COUNTA(filtered) *number_times,,0),COUNTA(filtered))+1),INDEX(filtered,SEQUENCE(COUNTA(filtered)*number_times,,1,1/number_times)))))```

Comment: I simplified the above lambda function;

```=LAMBDA(range,number_times,[grouped_stack],LET(r,ROWS(range),g,MAX(grouped_stack,0),s,SEQUENCE(r*number_times,,g,MAX(g/number_times,NOT(g))),INDEX(range,IF(g,s,MOD(s,r)+1))))```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a recursive `lambda` function naming it `_MultiVertical` with the `Name Manager` in `Formulas`:

> =LAMBDA(rng,acc,n,IF(n>1,_MultiVertical(rng,VSTACK(acc,rng),n-1),acc))

`rng` = the range to multiply 
`acc` = accumulator for adding with every iteration an additional `rng` and passing through at the end the result 
`n` = multiply n times vertically
For this recursive function you have to indicate the range to multiply twice. When the function calls itself the value of `rng` stays the same. It has to be passed through to add it to `acc`

[image: Example calling of _Multivertical]

2. To avoid to have to have two parameters which always will have the same value I created this wrapper function with the `Name Manager` calling it `MultiVertical`:

> =LAMBDA(rng,n,_MultiVertical(rng,rng,n))

This function calls the recursive function and passes through the range once as`rng` parameter and once as `acc` parameter.

[image: Example calling MultiVertical]

Answer (score -1):

If you know the range to repeat, I think this is simpler w/o the let function...but that's subjective.

```
=INDEX(range,MOD(SEQUENCE(COUNTA(range)*number_times,,0),COUNTA(range))+1)
=INDEX(range,SEQUENCE(COUNTA(range)*number_times,,1,1/number_times))
```

Just `hstack` these two formulas if you want one formula.